# States in ReactJs using ES6 and ES7

Tags: reactjs

In many examples I've see to manage state inside of a react component you will have to use getInitialState such as in this example.

```
var LikeButton = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {liked: false};
  },
  handleClick: function(event) {
    this.setState({liked: !this.state.liked});
  },
  render: function() {
    var text = this.state.liked ? 'like' : 'haven\'t liked';
    return (
      <p onClick={this.handleClick}>
        You {text} this. Click to toggle.
      </p>
    );
  }
});
```

But in ES6 syntax using getInitalState() will not work anymore. So how so you manage state in a react component using ES6 syntax?

An example is

```
// Future Version
export class Counter extends React.Component {
  static propTypes = { initialCount: React.PropTypes.number };
  static defaultProps = { initialCount: 0 };
  state = { count: this.props.initialCount };
  tick() {
    this.setState({ count: this.state.count + 1 });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div onClick={this.tick.bind(this)}>
        Clicks: {this.state.count}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

in ES6, The React team decided a more idiomatic way of initializing state was simply to store it in an instance variable setup in the constructor. This means you can refactor away your `getInitialState` method by moving its return value to be assigned to the `this.state` instance variable in your class' constructor.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class LikeButton extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { liked : false };
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this)
  }

  handleClick() {
    this.setState({
        liked : !this.state.liked
    });
  }

  render() {
    const text = this.state.liked ? 'like' : 'haven\'t liked';

    return (
        <p onClick={this.handleClick}>{`You ${text} this. Click to toggle.`}</p>
    );
  }
}
```

*NOTE:* you must bound your methods to a component instance

in ES6+ you can use [Property initializers](https://babeljs.io/blog/2015/06/07/react-on-es6-plus) feature

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class LikeButton extends Component {
  state = {
    liked : false
  }

  render() {
    const text = this.state.liked ? 'like' : 'haven\'t liked';
    const handleClick = ()=>{
      this.setState({
        liked : !this.state.liked
      });
    }

    return (
        <p onClick={this.handleClick}>{`You ${text} this. Click to toggle.`}</p>
    );
  }
}
```

*NOTE:* This is a [Stage 0](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1QbEE0BsO4lvl7NFTn5WXWeiEIBfaVUF7Dk0hpPpPDzU) proposal.

*NOTE:* i dropped the `constructor` so defined `handleClick` as nested function inside `render`

*Refrences:* [React official docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html#es6-classes) / [Article](http://www.newmediacampaigns.com/blog/refactoring-react-components-to-es6-classes)

Comment: Great thanks, I was putting handeClick function outside of reader and would get a null value error.

Comment: Although this is creating a new HandleClick function on EVERY RENDER not great

Answer (score 1):

In ES6 you initialize the state in the constructor. ie:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props)
  this.state = {} //or whatever
}
```

You can read more in the [official docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html#es6-classes)

Answer (score -1):

I think the issue may have been with the text inside the `<p>` tag. Try this code on for size:

```
const LikeButton = React.createClass({
    getInitialState() {
        return {
            liked : false
        };
    },

    handleClick() {
        this.setState({
            liked : !this.state.liked
        });
    },

    render() {
        const text = this.state.liked ? 'like' : 'haven\'t liked';

        return (
            <p onClick={this.handleClick}>{`You ${text} this. Click to toggle.`}</p>
        );
    }
});
```